# Modify CSV file using sed or any other command

Tags: awk, sed, removing-whitespace

I am trying to remove spaces and tabs from csv file. (*In Linux via command line*)

```
sed "s/[[:blank:]]\{1,\}//g" ./TRIM.csv
```

By using the above command, the space between value/item of a column is removed.

(Eg. **Hello World** is becoming **HelloWorld**)

Also I want to replace '|' with '~'

SAMPLE FILE:

```
   0 |         null |               0 |              0 |             0 |             null |  null |
   1 |         Hello World |               0 |              0 |             0 |             null |  null |
```

Desired output :

```
0~null~0~0~0~null~null~
1~Hello World~0~0~0~null~null~
```

***All*** spaces have been removed ***except*** the space between 'hello world' which is value of column that has space.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 sed -r 's/[[:space:]]+\|/~/g;s/~[[:space:]]+/~/g' file
```

Enable regular expression interpretation with -r or -E and then replace one or more spaces and then "|" with "~". After this, replace "~" followed by one or more spaces with "~"

Comment: Do it in one step: `s/[[:space:]]*\|[[:space:]]*/~/g`

Comment: `-r` makes it GNU-specific. If you used the equivalent `-E` then it'd work in both GNU and OSX/BSD seds (but only those). Either way you should state which sed(s) any non-POSIX answer requires.

Answer (score 5):

With your shown samples, could you please try following. Written and tested in GNU `awk` should work in any `awk`.

```
awk -F'[[:blank:]]*\\|[[:blank:]]*' -v OFS="~" '{sub(/^ +/,"");$1=$1}1' Input_file
```

Answer (score 1):

```
sed -e 's/[ \t]*|[ \t]*/~/g' -e 's/^ *\| *$//g'
#               ^                     ^
#               |                     |
#  Remove whitespace around     Replace leading and
#  | and replace it with ~      trailing whitespace
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 'y/|/\n/;s/.*/echo "&"|sed '\''s#^\\s*\\|\\s*$##g'\''/e;y/\n/~/' file
```

Translate `|`'s to `\n`'s.

Take the multiline result and apply a second invocation of sed to trim white space from the start and end of each line.

Translate the result turning `\n`'s back to `~`'s

Alternative:

```
sed -E 's/^\s*|\s*(\|)\s*|\s*$/\1/g;y/|/~/' file
```